# Epsilon delta proof for $\lim_\limits{x\to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}$ where $a>0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. For right limit, $x-a > 0$. Let $x-a < \delta$ then $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}) \lt \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$. Then chose we must choose $\epsilon $ so that $\epsilon > \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$. Is this correct? How would I conclude the proof?

**Edit - Follow up**

From answers, I try a proof for the same limit but this time Left side:

For left side limit, $x-a < 0$ so $a-x > 0$. Let $a-x < \delta$ then $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x} \lt \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x}} \lt \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{a}}$.

So let me begin the proof by saying to choose $\delta = \epsilon \sqrt a$ then $a-x \lt \delta $ so $(\sqrt a - \sqrt x )(\sqrt a + \sqrt x) \lt \epsilon \sqrt a$ so $\sqrt a - \sqrt x \lt \epsilon$

Comment: You cannot choose $\epsilon$. It is $\delta$ you need to choose.

Comment: What about the left limit? You must fix epsilon at the beginning! You don't have to find one! For every epsilon, you have to find appropriate delta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you **don't** choose $\varepsilon$. It can be *any* number greater than $0$. Then you take $\delta=\varepsilon{\sqrt a}$. Then\begin{align}|x-a|<\delta\iff&|x-a|<\varepsilon{\sqrt a}\\\iff&\bigl|\sqrt x-\sqrt a\bigr|\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt a\right)<\varepsilon\sqrt a\\\implies&\bigl|\sqrt x-\sqrt a\bigr|\sqrt a<\varepsilon\sqrt a\\\iff&\bigl|\sqrt x-\sqrt a\bigr|<\varepsilon.\end{align}Now, start all over again when $a=0$; what I wrote above doesn't work in that case, since $\delta$ would be $0$ then.

Comment: Thank you, I am already getting confused with epsilon delta. How do we know what $\delta $ to choose. Also I get confused whether delta is radius of neighbourhood of $x$ or $f(x)$

Comment: @jeea THere is no universal answer to the question “Which $\delta$ should I choose?” And $\delta$ is about $x$, not about $f(x)$.

Comment: Please see my edit, have I written my second part properly, actually I understand your proof, you have done both together.. :) Thanks alot

Comment: @jeea Actually, I don't understand what you wrote. For instance, what is the left side limit? And how is it possible that no absolute values appear here?

Comment: I mean left side limit means that $x<a$ but $x\to a$

Comment: @jeea It is not correct. If you choose $\delta=\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt a}$, what your computations show is that $\sqrt a-\sqrt x<\frac\varepsilon a$.

Comment: Thank you I understand

Answer (score 3):

For  $x >0$, $a>0$:

$|√x-√a| =\dfrac {|x-a|}{√x+√a}\lt$

$\dfrac{|x-a|}{√a}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta \le \epsilon √a.$

Then

$|x-a| \lt \delta$ implies

$|√x-√a| \lt \dfrac{|x-a|}{√a} \lt $

$\dfrac{\delta}{√a} \le\epsilon.$

Answer (score 2):

For any $\varepsilon >0$ you must find apropriate $\delta$

$$\sqrt{x} > \sqrt{a} \implies \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}>2\sqrt{a} \implies  {1\over \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}<{1\over 2\sqrt{a}}$$

So take $\delta = 2\sqrt{a}\cdot\varepsilon$

Comment: It makes sense to me, so if we go from left side We would have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{a}} > \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a}}$ so how would we choose $\delta$ then?

Comment: what if $0<a < 1$ ? should i use separate cases?

Comment: Thank you Christian for help, I have given vote but dont know who is down voting.