# limit proof with epsilon-delta for ${\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I am having difficulties solving $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}}$ . How can I find $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$ without $x$ ?

Comment: This has been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800305/epsilon-delta-proof-for-lim-x-to-a-sqrtx-sqrta-where-a0?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Epsilon delta proof for $\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}$ where $a&gt;0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800305/epsilon-delta-proof-for-lim-x-to-a-sqrtx-sqrta-where-a0)